# Apache problem.Failed to start

Tags: apache2

I have problem with apache2 (or something else) when i do install apache2. Then i started to reinstall and this happens:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/95,5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mysql-server' missing; assuming pack
age has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mysql-server-8.0' missing; assuming 
package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mysql-common' missing; assuming pack
age has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mysql-client-core-8.0' missing; assu
ming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mysql-server-core-8.0' missing; assu
ming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mysql-client-8.0' missing; assuming 
package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 177193 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../apache2_2.4.41-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apache2 (2.4.41-1ubuntu1) over (2.4.41-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up apache2 (2.4.41-1ubuntu1) ...
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error cod
e.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "restart" failed.
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: 
enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-10-18 23:48:36 EEST; 5ms ag
o
     Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
  Process: 10605 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=127)

жов 18 23:48:36 name systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
жов 18 23:48:36 name apachectl[10605]: /usr/sbin/apachectl: 174: /usr/sbin/apache
2: not found
жов 18 23:48:36 name apachectl[10605]: Action 'start' failed.
жов 18 23:48:36 name apachectl[10605]: The Apache error log may have more informa
tion.
жов 18 23:48:36 name systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=ex
ited, status=127/n/a
жов 18 23:48:36 name systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
жов 18 23:48:36 name systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Processing triggers for systemd (242-7ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.7-3) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.36-1ubuntu3) ...
```

when i do type

```
journalctl -xe
-- 
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit apache2.service has exited.
-- 
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 127.
жов 19 00:14:44 name systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit apache2.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-cod
жов 19 00:14:44 name systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: A start job for unit apache2.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit apache2.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 20214 and the job result is failed.
жов 19 00:14:44 name sudo[14155]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user
жов 19 00:15:00 name xdg-desktop-por[2472]: Failed to get application states: GDB
жов 19 00:15:01 name CRON[14237]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user
жов 19 00:15:01 name CRON[14238]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null &
жов 19 00:15:01 name CRON[14237]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user
```

Comment: Related: [apache2 service is masked](https://askubuntu.com/q/1177310/968501)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that mysql needs to be reinstalled (note the warnings in your post about mysql). Have a look at this post: [how to reinstall mysql?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265685/how-to-reinstall-mysql#348484)